# Inject Text between <p> which resides inside a <div>

Tags: jquery

I've got something like this:

```
<div id="myId">
     <p></p>
</div>
```

I want to inject some simple text between the `<p></p>` tags but now sure not to reference that on the dom by going first through the div then its related `<p>`

I'm using the very latest version of jQuery as of today's date.

Comment: lol @ 7 answers within a minute

Comment: Why didnt you use google, though?

Comment: @Mike Trusov: the easier the question - the more you get answers

Comment: so amazed that a user with 4k rep need to ask such an easy question like this

Comment: How is a rep indicator of the question asked??

Comment: @Sushanth --: actually I also would assume that person with 600+ questions knows how to use google

Answer (score 1):

Use this selector  `$('#myId p')`

To insert text you can use `.html()`

**jQuery**

```
$('#myId p').html('Hello World')
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/KCY5U/1/)**

**Pure Javascript**

```
var children = document.getElementById("myId").children;
for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if(children[i].tagName == 'P') {
        children[i].innerHTML = 'Hello World !!';
    }
}​
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Y96hc/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use the child selector

```
$("#myId > p").text('a');
```

Answer (score 1):

to inject text

```
$('#myId').find('p').text('Hello');
```

to inject html

```
$('#myId').find('p').html('<h1>Hello</h1>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
$("#myId p").text("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#myID p').text('content');`  should do it

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work: $("#myID p").text("asdf")

Answer (score 0):

you can do by  this way

if it is only text than

```
 $('#myId p').text('your text');
```

if it is only html code like span or something else than

```
 $('#myId p').html('your hmtl');
```